# Using a function or file for a database connection

Tags: php, function, pdo

I am having a really hard time understanding why I cannot do either of two things:

- Wrap a PDO database connection in a function
- Store a PDO database connection in a separate file and require it on load

So I have a file: **db_connect.php**

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx;charset=utf8', 'xxx', 'xxx');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I know this does connect to my db. Trouble is when I

```
require_once('db_connect.php');
//or
include('db_connect.php');
```

Into my **functions.php** it doesn't seem to load the connection. If I move the contents from db_connect.php into my function which has some SQL command:

```
function doStuff(){
//Copy and paste db_connect.php
$var= $db->prepare('SELECT .........
}
```

It works. What is the issue here? I thought it was because $db is not established outside of "try/catch" but globally declaring it

```
$db;
```

didn't help. I also moved the contents of db_connect.php into it's own function db_connect() within **functions.php**

```
function doStuff(){
db_connect();
$var= $db->prepare('SELECT ...
}
```

And no luck! I TRULY can't understand how that wouldn't work..

Comment: You should read up on variable scope. Your `$db` variable is not in the scope of the function in your first function example. Just pass it as a parameter and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You was right, **$db** is a **local variable**. You have two choice :

- Return **$db** variable from **db_connect()** and use it
- Store **$db** into superglobal **$GLOBALS["db"]**

Comment: Sigh no luck. Returning $db doesn't do anything. Do I need to declare $db outside of function db_connect() as well? I placed everything in one file/

Comment: Put the return inner the Try and not after the catch in db_connect()

Comment: I dont know how to do PHp in jsfiddle. Either way still does nothing :(  http://jsfiddle.net/RNt3N/

Answer (score 0):

With an MVC work flow:

in my model, I have a db_connect file with:

```
try{
    $this->db = new PDO($hostname,$username,$password);
}

catch (Exception $e) { 
  echo 'ERROR: unable to connect to remote DB. Try again or contact     Web Master - dbcp'; exit;
}
```

also in my model file

```
<?php
class FunStuff
{
private $db

public function __construct()
{
    include 'config_DB.php';
}

private function isValidAdminLogin($userName, $password)
{
    // boolean return
    $password = sha1($password);
    $query = 'SELECT adminID FROM admin WHERE adminName = :username AND password = :password';
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':username', $userName);
    $statement->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $statement->execute();
    if($statement->rowCount() == 1){return true;}
    else {return false;}
}
}
```